# Custom eCommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce, tracking

I am selling different software on my website and am offering a 30 days free trial. Is there someway that I can track the trial in Google Analytics?

(And maybe, after the 30 days run out if they do not order remove them from the GA data?)

What would be your recommended solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to remove their data from Google Analytics, unless you filter them out explicitly from whatever report you don't want to see them in.

Google also offer an [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/) for using Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create a goal and then track those that extend beyond thirty days possibly with another goal.